# XSLT : How do i assign Constant value using XML element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

We have input XML. In that,We tried to put constant value using   `<LineActionType>`  element.

We basically want to add  `<LineActionType >A<LineActionType />` this element  constant value on each Comment Line Tag.
that is

```
 <CommentLine>
                    <Comment>Comment#1</Comment>
                    <OrderLineID>OR-1810143</OrderLineID>
                    <UserDefined>3</UserDefined>
                    <LineActionType >A<LineActionType />
                 </CommentLine>
```

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SalesOrders xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORTOIDOC.XSD">
   <Orders>
      <OrderHeader>
         <CustomerPoNumber>Manual Order 1</CustomerPoNumber>
         <OrderActionType>A</OrderActionType>
      </OrderHeader>
      <OrderDetails>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>abc-1</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>ASSEMBLED</StockDescription>
            <OrderQty>2.0</OrderQty>
            <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
            <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>1</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810141</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>FBX-SMO30029-8</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>TARGET SOAP PDQ 2014 ASSEMBLED</StockDescription>
            <OrderQty>3.0</OrderQty>
            <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
            <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>2</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810142</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <CommentLine>
            <Comment>Comment#1</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810143</OrderLineID>
            <UserDefined>3</UserDefined>
            <LineActionType />
         </CommentLine>
         <CommentLine>
            <Comment>Comment#2</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810144</OrderLineID>
            <UserDefined>4</UserDefined>
            <LineActionType />
         </CommentLine>
      </OrderDetails>
   </Orders>
</SalesOrders>
```

We tried following XSLT 2.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="Windows-1252" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="OrderDetails">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
            <xsl:sort select="xs:integer(UserDefined)" />
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="StockLine[not(StockCodeDescription) and not (OrderQty) and not(Price)]">
      <CommentLine>
         <Comment>
            <xsl:value-of select="StockCode" />
         </Comment>
         <xsl:copy-of select="OrderLineID" />
         <xsl:copy-of select="UserDefined" />
        </CommentLine>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="CommentLine[OrderLineID = preceding-sibling::StockLine/OrderLineID and not(Comment)]" />
   <xsl:template match="CommentLine[some $sib in preceding-sibling::CommentLine satisfies deep-equal(., $sib)]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SalesOrders xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORTOIDOC.XSD">
   <Orders>
      <OrderHeader>
         <CustomerPoNumber>Manual Order 1</CustomerPoNumber>
         <OrderActionType>A</OrderActionType>
      </OrderHeader>
      <OrderDetails>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>abc-1</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>ASSEMBLED</StockDescription>
            <OrderQty>2.0</OrderQty>
            <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
            <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>1</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810141</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <StockCode>FBX-SMO30029-8</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>TARGET SOAP PDQ 2014 ASSEMBLED</StockDescription>
            <OrderQty>3.0</OrderQty>
            <OrderUom>EA</OrderUom>
            <PriceUom>EA</PriceUom>
            <AlwaysUsePriceEntered>Y</AlwaysUsePriceEntered>
            <UserDefined>2</UserDefined>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810142</OrderLineID>
         </StockLine>
         <CommentLine>
            <Comment>Comment#1</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810143</OrderLineID>
            <UserDefined>3</UserDefined>
            <LineActionType >A<LineActionType />
         </CommentLine>
         <CommentLine>
            <Comment>Comment#2</Comment>
            <OrderLineID>OR-1810144</OrderLineID>
            <UserDefined>4</UserDefined>
           <LineActionType >A<LineActionType />
         </CommentLine>
      </OrderDetails>
   </Orders>
</SalesOrders>
```

ANY help on it would be much appreciated ?

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly note that `<LineActionType >A<LineActionType />` is not valid XML, so I am assuming you mean `<LineActionType>A</LineActionType>`.

Anyway, if all `CommentLine` elements had a `LineActionType` and you just wanted to set them all to `A`, you could just add this template along with the identity template

```
<xsl:template match="CommentLine/LineActionType">
   <xsl:copy>A</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, if `LineActionType` is not always present under a `CommentLine`, you could try adding these two templates instead. One to add it under any `CommentLine`, and another to prevent any existing one being output (so that it doesn't get output twice)

```
<xsl:template match="CommentLine">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      <LineActionType>A</LineActionType>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CommentLine/LineActionType" />
```

Comment: When i am trying to apply both given templates . it did not work for me.

Comment: it is not generating syntax error . but also not creating  constant  value.

Comment: See http://xsltransform.net/pPJ8LUM or http://xsltransform.net/bwdwru to see the two possibilities in action, both of which produce your expected output based on the input. One things to be wary of is adding other templates to your XSLT that also match `CommentLine`, so you may need to add a `priority` attribute. Also, the XSLT in your question you have a template that creates a `CommentLine` from a `StockLine`. If you wanted this to contain `LineActionType` too, simply add it as part of this existing template.